# Some links cannot be downloaded in <a href download> tag

Tags: html

I can download simple links (eg 'x.jpg').
But some links can't download whatever I do.

Like this :

```html
<a href="/instagram.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a122a6b090b0d08fb29054a58e4ba1d8/5E6244BC/t51.2885-15/e35/73020566_1906916579453459_3610340591421234923_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=1&amp;se=7&amp;ig_cache_key=MjE1Mzk3NTkyNTE1NTgyMjI1NA%3D%3D.2" download>
            download
</a>
```

Results : 
*************************** 
Main Result : downloaded (73020566.html) (fail! , no file) 
if i include to end of filename '.jpg' : same result, 
include to start of filename 'https://' : this photo openning in tab. 
*************************** 
I would appreciate it if someone who knows the solution helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As j08691 stated, using the download attribute won't work since your download is cross-origin. However, you could try download.js, which uses AJAX to load the file content into a blob and download it: http://danml.com/download.html

Answer (score 1):

The `download` attribute only works for "[same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)" So you can't use it when linking to another site. Also, "/ and \ characters are converted to underscores (_). Filesystems may forbid other characters in filenames, so browsers will adjust the suggested name if necessary."